# Is there a way to exclude a specific file from epydoc generation?

Tags: python, epydoc

I'm generating an epydoc for a library of code, and there are a few testing files scattered throughout that I'd like to not include.  I could use the `--exclude` generation option and rename the files, but I'm wondering if there's anything I can add to the files themselves that will be interpreted by epydoc as a command not to include/parse that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would seem the answer to this question is no.  If you want to exclude an element, the only option is to use

> --exclude=PATTERN

Which excludes modules whose dotted name matches the regular expression PATTERN

Answer (score 0):

You can also specified the excluded file in the config file like:

exclude: my_module.my_class